# Is it possible to use local variable as filter in DataTable.Compute expression?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to use my local variable (which is date from Calendar in string format) to filter DataTable rows. Is it possible to do that?

```
private void Calendar_SelectedDatesChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{

    var tb = sender as System.Windows.Controls.Calendar;
    CollectionViewSource addedFoodsViewSource = ((CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("addedFoodsViewSource")));

    if (tb == null)
    {
        fooddatabaseDataSet1.AddedFoodsDataTable dt = addedFoodsViewSource.Source as fooddatabaseDataSet1.AddedFoodsDataTable;
        dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = null;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        string txt = tb.SelectedDate.ToString();

        fooddatabaseDataSet1.AddedFoodsDataTable dt = addedFoodsViewSource.Source as fooddatabaseDataSet1.AddedFoodsDataTable;
        dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("AddedDate LIKE '%{0}%'", txt);
        string total = dt.Compute("Sum(AddedFat)", "AddedDate = ???").ToString();
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(total);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        {
            string txt = tb.SelectedDate.ToString();
            
            fooddatabaseDataSet1.AddedFoodsDataTable dt = addedFoodsViewSource.Source as fooddatabaseDataSet1.AddedFoodsDataTable;
            dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("AddedDate LIKE '%{0}%'", txt);

           string totalfat = dt.Compute("Sum(AddedFat)", dt.DefaultView.RowFilter).ToString();             
           testtb.Text = totalfat;
        }
```

Comment: That one worked for me. Just copied rowfilter name.